# Broken Latex Layer in Spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs, auctex

I write LaTeX using Spacemacs, and suddenly (I think ever since is updated all of my packages) running `latex/build` fails with:

```
TeX-command-expand: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil
```

Below is the backtrace for the error using `debug-on-error` set to `t`:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
  string-match("\\(?: \"\\\\\\|\"\\|%\\(?:(\\(?:\\(?:O\\?\\(?:aux\\|idx\\|pdf\\)\\..." nil nil)
  TeX-command-expand(nil)
  TeX-command("LatexMk" TeX-master-file -1)
  (progn (let ((TeX-save-query nil)) (TeX-save-document (TeX-master-file))) (TeX-command latex-build-command 'TeX-master-file -1))
  latex/build()
  funcall-interactively(latex/build)
  call-interactively(latex/build nil nil)
  command-execute(latex/build)
```

Also, when loading my configuration I get another error which I think may be related:

```
Error (use-package): tex/:config: Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, tex-buf
```

When looking at the trace for that error, it looks like `auctex-latexmk.el` tries to `(require 'tex-buf)` but cant find it. Older versions of `auctex` than the one spacemacs installed (13.1.3) have a file named `tex-buf.el`, and mine doesn't, so I'm guessing this is some compatibility issue between `auctex-latexmk` (version 20170618.1636) and `auctex`.

I tried reinstalling Emacs and re-cloning Spacemacs, but the problems persists. I'm unsure how to solve this, and I don't really understand if the two errors shown above are actually related or not.

Comment: For the second error, here is a [PR](https://github.com/tom-tan/auctex-latexmk/pull/40) for it. You can change on your side temporarily.

Comment: Sorry for sounding pedantic, but when you encounter a bug in Spacemacs, it is good practice to first check the issues/PR's [there](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs), and if you don't find an existing issue/PR then open an issue there. Or for, usually, even faster answers, visit the [Spacemacs gitter](https://gitter.im/syl20bnr/spacemacs/).

Comment: I applied the patch, Spacemacs deleted it and brought it back to the original version, and somehow it fixed both Errors. I'm so confused...
@dalanicolai, thank you for your reply, will do next time. (Looks like https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/15467 refers exactly to my problem...)